# How to change the plot line color from blue to black

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am stuck when I have generated a set of data and tried to color the plot line in python.

For example I would like to change the line color from blue to black here.

This is what I have and returns is the set of data that I got from pandas.

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('#cccccc')
returns.plot()
```

[image: Screenshot of plot]

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The usual way to set the line color in matplotlib is to specify it in the plot command. This can either be done by a string after the data, e.g. `"r-"` for a red line, or by explicitely stating the `color` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [2,3,1], "r-") # red line
plt.plot([1,2,3], [5,5,3], color="blue") # blue line

plt.show()
```

See also the [plot command's documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

In case you already have a line with a certain color, you can change that with the `lines2D.set_color()` method.

```
line, = plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,3], color="blue")
line.set_color("black")
```

---

Setting the color of a line in a pandas plot is also best done at the point of creating the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ "x" : [1,2,3,5], "y" : [3,5,2,6]})
df.plot("x", "y", color="r") #plot red line

plt.show()
```

If you want to change this color later on, you can do so by

```
plt.gca().get_lines()[0].set_color("black")
```

This will get you the first (possibly the only) line of the current active axes.
In case you have more axes in the plot, you could loop through them

```
for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
    ax.get_lines()[0].set_color("black")
```

and if you have more lines you can loop over them as well.

Comment: How to update the legend after doing this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one plot line and you want to set a different color for each line,
use the attribute below in your plot() where each index represents a line color for a column.

```
color=['color1','color2']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the object after creation (for instance after "seasonal_decompose"), you can always access and edit the properties of the plot; for instance, changing the color of the first subplot from blue to black:

`plt.axes[0].get_lines()[0].set_color('black')`